# What part of mathematics would one say that the derivative is part of?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis, derivatives

Suppose that people do not define "Analysis" as an area of mathematics. Would it make more sense to think (intuitively) of the derivative as part of topology or geometry. (Here, topology is the idea of nearness and geometry is the idea of angle/direction (and possibly measure).)

Comment: I would say that it is part of Calculus... do you consider that an area of mathematics?

Comment: From a false premise anything follows.

Comment: Intuitively, I do not think of the derivative as the slope of the tangent line.  Of course it is the slope of the tangent line, but that is not always the most useful model.  I tend to think of it as sensitivity. (elasticity, leverage, etc.)

Comment: @Nilknarf Most naturally, one would say that it is part of Calculus. But in this context, I am considering Calculus and Analysis to be the same subject.

Comment: Or it could be part of function/polynomial theory and an extension of finite derivatives...

Comment: For me, derivatives we always part of algebra, while calculus containing the rigor required to use derivatives in certain contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Derivatives and integrals have a clear geometric interpretation in slopes and areas. More rigorous definitions tend to use measure theory, which you have classed as geometry.

I can't think of an intuitive topological interpretation. There does seem to be such a thing as a [topological derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_derivative), but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

So if it has to be classified as one of the two, geometry seems the the better fit.

Comment: Topologically, I was thinking along along the lines that the derivative can be seen as a limit of ratios of distance (nearness) in a suitable topological vector space.

Comment: In order to have a concept of distance, you need to have a metric, which is a stronger condition than just having a topology. And at that point, well, it's called geo*metry* for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one could argue that a derivative is part of number theory, because a derivative is a number.

Derivatives are part of calculus.

There is definitely a geometric interpretation and representation of derivatives.

In your context, I suppose there is a topological interpretation, but that's intertwined with the geometric viewpoint.

Comment: "Number theory" usually mean study of _integers_.

Comment: Number theory? Surely you are joking.